# Not able to draw shadows using UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiview, uikit

I am trying convert an UIView into an UIImage using UIGraphicsImageRenderer. I have applied shadows on my UIView but shadows gets removed in output image.
Here's my code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: compressedImage.size))
view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
view.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 2, height: 2)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let rendereredImage = renderer.image { ctx in
     view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

if you assign this rendereredImage to an UIImageView you can see that there are no shadows.
can you tell me what's happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a shadow, the bounds of the view do not change. The shadow appears *outside* of the bounds of the view. If the size of the image is `view.bounds`, then the shadow will be cut off.

A simple way to fix this is to put the view inside a slightly larger superview:

```
let view = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 2, y: 2), size: compressedImage.size))
view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
view.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 2, height: 2)

let superView = UIView(frame: .init(
    x: 0, y: 0, 
    width: compressedImage.size.width + 5, 
    height: compressedImage.size.height + 5
))
superview.backgroundColor = .clear
superView.addSubview(view)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: superView.bounds.size)
let rendereredImage = renderer.image { ctx in
    superView.drawHierarchy(in: superView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

Alternatively, consider using `view.layer.render(in:)`.

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: -5).size)
let rendereredImage = renderer.image { ctx in
    view.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
}
```